# How to create a back item in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I would like the home item look like the back button in the ActionBar in Android 3.0 app. The look is similar to Market app (see the screenshot below marked in red):
[image]
I know there is a standard method to add an "up" affordance to the home button in action bar. But haven't seen a standard way to add a back arrow.
Is there a standard way to do it (maybe subclassing of ActionBar/Activity etc.)? If anyone has an example or has done something like this - it would be very nice if you could share it.  Thank you.

UPD: if I use `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`, it adds an up affordance as this - see a tiny up arrow on the left:
[image]

Maybe there is a way to style this "up" arrow to be a "back" arrow?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> But haven't seen a standard way to add a back arrow.

That *is* the "up" affordance. Call `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` on your `ActionBar` to toggle it on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it appears as the screenshot #2 (I attached to the question)

Comment: @justadreamer: On an Android 3.2 environment, `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` displays with the leftward-pointing arrowhead as in your first screenshot.

Comment: ok, I have Android 3.1 running - and in Market app it displays the back button like in the first example, and in my app the home button displays the up arrow as in my second screenshot. So Market app apparently uses something else, am I wrong?

Comment: @justadreamer: Most likely, they just are using `android:logo` to put in their own image that has the arrowhead. Personally, I recommend that you simply use `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` and allow the platform to supply the correct artwork for that platform. This way, you maintain fidelity with other applications... except the Market. My guess is that the northwest-pointing arrowhead was deemed too tiny, particularly when shown in gray, so they switched to the larger arrowhead for 3.2, and Market elected to manually switch for earlier OS versions as well.